# I need help getting my bot to respond a different response each time

Tags: ruby, tumblr, bots

I'm making a joke bot for tumblr that responds to question-askers with some variation of "Greetings [asker name here], piss. Yours truly, Pissy Boy.". I'm trying to include 4 possible responses instead of just one catch-all response, which is where I've hit a snag. Here's the entirety of my current code for the bot (The bot is being written using Ruby in Ubuntu):

```
require 'tumblr_client'
USERNAME = "thepissbot"
def piss
  # Authenticate via OAuth
  client = Tumblr::Client.new({
    :consumer_key => ENV['CONSUMER_KEY'],
    :consumer_secret => ENV['CONSUMER_SECRET'],
    :oauth_token => ENV['OAUTH_TOKEN'],
    :oauth_token_secret => ENV['OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET']
  })
  # Make the request
  asks = client.submissions(USERNAME, limit: 5)['posts']
  asks.each do |ask|
    if ask ['type'] !='answer'
      piss
      return
      response1 = "Greetings #{ask['asking_name']}, piss. Yours truly, Pissy Boy."
      response2 = "Dear, #{ask['asking_name']}, piss. Love, Pissy Boy."
      response3 = "Salutations #{ask['asking_name']}, piss. Sincerely, Pissy Boy."
      response4 = "What's up, #{ask['asking_name']}? Piss. Your friend, Pissy Boy."
      array=(response1 response2 response3 response4)
      tags = "piss mail"
      client.edit(USERNAME,
        id: ask['id'],
        answer: array,
        state: 'published',
        tags: tags
      )
    end
  end
end
```

This supposedly "works", according to the terminal. However, when I check the inbox for the bot, the test ask I had sent it remains unanswered, and that's certainly not expected behavior. I think it has something to do with the way I'm dealing with the array.
This has been a problem for 2 days now... I feel like it should be super-simple but I'm just missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you fix the indentation of the code?

Comment: That's actually how I have it written...

Comment: ...why? Are you charged by the whitespace character?

Comment: I have it written like this because I haven't formatted it properly yet. I'm trying to get the code working first before formatting, hence why I asked the question.
Also, no, I don't believe I am charged by the whitespace character.

Comment: formatting shouldn't be something you put off. you should always format code as it is written. I'll do it for you now, it will take like 20 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, max pleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Ok now that your code is formatted correctly the error is obvious:

```
if ask ['type'] !='answer'
  piss
  return
  ... (some other code)
```

this `early` return will cause the entire `piss` method to finish. Unless there's some purpose to this `return` call remove it.

This should make the benefits of formatting code obvious; you can more easily see which `if`, `each`, `def` block a line of code is being run.

Comment: I removed the `return` call and ran it again and it still didn't respond to the ask at all. It's still sitting in my inbox. However, this does make sense... I can't believe I didn't catch that earlier... Oops.

Comment: are you sure `answer` should be an array and not string such as `array.sample`? I don't know the Tumblr API, so I can't help you much further.

Comment: Making it `array.sample` doesn't seem to fix it either... Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: `piss` method. LOL